# How to leverage memsql for reports that combining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, bigdata, data-warehouse, singlestore

We using memsql columnar-store database.
We create pipeline for each “even-type” in our backend architecture and we create a dedicated table for it (we call it “source table”). so each pipeline writes to one table (aka source table) on memsql

We have different business reports for customers that consist data from multiple source tables (not necessary tables that we can join because some fields can be existed on one table and some not)

So the only way to overcome this is to create huge and complicated queries which consists UNION functions making things much hard to maintenance and understand

What would be best practice to maintain and keep such architecture which will allow us to create multiple reports on multiple source tables and to reduce query complexity.

one way we thought is doing dedicated view per report. but we are not sure if we shall go that way. we need to create external ETA’s that will add more and more data to that view (a daily process)
what’s your thoughts regarding this? is that could be a way?

second way just to manipulate tremendous queries with UNION functions (on run-time)
We dont like this way because it run complexity on run-time on query time

I want to mention that those reports dont need to be updated on real-time. we can have buffer (hours) from one update to another

thoughts?

Comment: Why have you added a amazon-redshift tag? Please remove if not related.

Comment: Because its based on the same technology.. columnstore database

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible strategies: optimize for reads or optimize for writes.  You have a pipeline that ingests data quickly to the "source" table.  This is definitely optimized for writes.  But now you're struggling with reads.  A view isn't a bad approach, but the join cost comes at each report run.

Consider having the pipeline (or another pipeline) denormalize the data into the format needed for the report.  This isn't a view with embedded joins, but rather another storage of the data specific to the read in question.  (Yes, duplicate data, but storage is cheap, and assuming the report is used often, this strategy moves the transformational compute to a single calculation on ingest, not repeated on each report run.)

If you find you often need to join standard data for different reports or the reports are more ad-hock, consider altering the "source" table schemas to include these fields, and populate them during pipeline ingest.  Then you can use simpler queries to achieve speed without duplicate tables.  Denormalized data like this definitely has an element of duplication -- so writes are more complex -- but reads are much more efficient.

Comment: so you suggest to use the pipelines to create dedicated tables for reports. that means we dont need "source" tables anymore as we will query the dedicated reports all the time. also we need to modify our pipelines all the times(according to reports requests)

Comment: Right. That's an option to consider. Maybe this moves computation to the front, eliminating it on each report run. Maybe your business needs dictate that this isn't a good move, and you could consider other options.

Comment: what I find problematic here is how you going to feed those pipelines? i mean we have kafa pipelines which listen to different topics. if we consider your way that means we will have to send all our "persistent" events to one topic only. meaning all our business services need to send their "audit" messages to that topic  so we can have multiple pipelines being fed by that topic into different tables. is that can be considered as common practice?

Comment: the problem here also might be performances. because we will have multiple pipelines that listen to one topic. meanings pipelines going to discard messages that not relevant to them

Comment: Interesting. So a report spans multiple Kafka topics. Sounds like a pipeline that denormalizes the data wouldn't work since it doesn't have access to all the data at once.

Comment: even if I could produce all our transactions into one topic - having multiple pipelines listening from one big topic will be less effecient as each pipeline will discard messages that not belongs to it.. thats huge performance impact isnt it?

Comment: Or create one pipeline that pulls all messages into a stored procedure, and have the stored procedure denormalize the content, and insert into the correct table(s).